# Centering new dialog window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, window

So I have a user control within a window that creates a new dialog window when a button is clicked.  I would like the window to appear on top of the window calling it.  I tried to do this...

```
        NewDialog dlg = new NewDialog();
        dlg.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        dlg.ShowDialog();
```

The problem is the owner doesn't seem to be the calling window (maybe because a user control is making the call and not an actual window?).  So I tried adding this...

```
        dlg.Owner = Application.Current.Windows[0];
```

Which mostly works, but it is not a generic solution as sometimes my new windows have to call a new window, and I want them centered on the calling window, not the primary window.  Is there a better way to set the owner correctly to the window the user control it is a part of?  I have tried many variations that all seem to have some quirk where the window comes up in a completely different place, or something doesn't evaluate right and throws an error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ^-- throws a compiler error, cannot convert the user control type to 'window'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `this` is not of type `Window` use static [Window.GetWindow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow.aspx) to get the host window.

```
dlg.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
```